# C++ array with wrong input

Tags: c++

So I wrote this program to code to read in a number of ints, and then its supposed to read the array back to backwards. however, it just reads back all 0s

```
while (true)
{
    cin >> input;
    if (input == -1 && gotStuff == false) {return 0;}
    else if (input == -1 && gotStuff == true) {break;}
    else
    {
        inputData[pos1] = input;
        pos1 ++;
        gotStuff = true;
    }
}

for (int i = pos1; i >= 0; i--)
{
    outputData[pos2] = inputData[pos1];
    pos2 ++;

    cout << outputData[pos1] << " ";
}
```

Why is this reading back as all 0s?

Comment: Use `int i = pos1 - 1;` Use `inputData[i]` instead of `inputData[pos1]` inside the second loop. Also, `pos2` is not declared anywhere.

Comment: Your logic looks pretty flawed. Why don't you simply use `while(cin >> input)`? Or do you want to avoid reading negative numbers from cin?

Comment: if the user inputs -1, I want to a) end the loop, or b) exit the program

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have a clear problem here

```
for (int i = pos1; i >= 0; i--)
{
    outputData[pos2] = inputData[pos1];
    pos2 ++;

    cout << outputData[pos1] << " ";
}
```

because you always try to print `outputData[pos1]` but `pos1` is never changed within your loop. Therefore you always output the same character. Similarly you are always copying the same character of `inputData` to the `outputData` array so when the loop exits, `outputData` will just contain the same character at different indices.

You might have better luck with the following loop which at least copies and prints the correct characters

```
pos2 = 0;
for (int i = pos1-1; i >= 0; i--)
{
    outputData[pos2] = inputData[i];
    cout << outputData[pos2] << " ";
    pos2++;

}
```

You may have other problems with your code too as you do not show us in the question what the values of `pos1` and `pos2` have been initialised with.

Comment: Also, you have to begin at `pos1 - 1`.

Comment: @Flotolk Not sure what else to suggest then. Take a look at `std::vector<int>` though to store your values and use reverse iterator or the `reverse` function.

Comment: @mathematician1975 can you pint me anywhere to see how to use that? I'm still new to c++

Answer (score 0):

When you loop through the array here:

```
for (int i = pos1; i >= 0; i--)
{
    outputData[pos2] = inputData[pos1];
    pos2 ++;

    cout << outputData[pos1] << " ";
}
```

you are always accessing the same position: `pos1` in your input data. If you change this loop to this

```
for (int i = pos1 - 1; i >= 0; i--)
{
    outputData[pos2] = inputData[i];
    pos2 ++;

    cout << outputData[pos2 - 1] << " ";
}
```

it will count down like you intended it to. That is because i is decremented with every iteration of the loop, while pos1 is not. It was probably reading all 0s because `inputData[pos1]` was 0.

Comment: You have to begin at `pos1 - 1`.

Comment: pos1 and pos2 start at 0

Comment: @Flotolk `pos1` would be incremented in the while loop when the input is being read. `pos2` already being at 0 would work fine with the example.